# MS Graph API administration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

How can I view all subscriptions regardless of the 'app registration' that created it?

On our AAD, we have 2 'App Registration', lets call them regAppA & regAppB. We ran into an issue where we used both apps to create subscription for outlook events. This resulted in multiple events firing for a single change which caused issues down the line when handling them.

The problem is if you call :
`GET https://graphUrl/subscriptions` **(with regAppA secret)** you will only get the subscriptions created using that App Registration, and likewise with *regAppB's secret*

To avoid this situation happening again, I would like to run an automated script/program/whatever, that would get all subscriptions created regardless of the App Registration used to create it and flag issues found in the data.

I could do that using https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, but I don't know how-to or if you can use delegated authentication programatically. I need this solution to run with no user intervention.

Any help will be much appreciated.